# How to escape a quoted tab when tab is also field delimiter. Field optionally enclosed by is not working

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to ingest a csv file, the field delimiter is a tab, in one particular column I have a string value surrounded by double quotes that has a tab.

I have tried to use the escape unenclosed field with \t,
this results in an error:

```
get: value [\t] for parameter ‘ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD’ conflict with parameter ‘FIELD_DELIMITER’
```

I have also specified my file format something like this:

```
FILE_FORMAT = (
  TYPE = CSV
  RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n'
  SKIP_HEADER = 0
  FIELD_DELIMITER = '\t'
  FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY =  '\042' -- have tried '"' also 
  ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\011'
  TRIM_SPACE = TRUE
  EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL=TRUE
  NULL_IF = ''
);
```

However, Snowflake is still unable to parse the column correctly.

Raw Data which causes the problem:

```
"<STRING> <TAB><STRING>"
```

After running my Copy Into command, the values inside the columns looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='0x27'`?

Comment: @Sergiu thanks for the suggestion, I just tried it, but it's not escaping correctly, the resulting data looks the same.

Comment: @Asher Can you share a sample CSV file to repro the issue? Please paste the content as code block. You can anonymize the data as long as we can repro the issue.